# Npgsql - Using "GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY"

Tags: npgsql

I'm currently trying to use Npgsql (version 3.1.3) to insert a record into a table with a generated identity using the official documentation ([Npgsql.org](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/modeling/generated-properties.html)) . But I always get the error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 428C9: cannot insert into column "mitteilung_id"
```

I have already found several questions about this topic, but they are either outdated (version 2 or lower) or do not work.

My project is structured as follows. The table definition looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mitteilung
(
    mitteilung_id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_pk
            PRIMARY KEY,
    betreff       TEXT
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_nn_betreff
            CHECK (betreff IS NOT NULL)
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_ck_length_betreff
            CHECK (length(betreff) <= 100),
    nachricht     TEXT
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_ck_length_nachricht
            CHECK (length(nachricht) <= 500)
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_nn_nachricht
            CHECK (nachricht IS NOT NULL),
    erfasst_am    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
        CONSTRAINT mitteilung_nn_erfasst_am
            CHECK (erfasst_am IS NOT NULL)
);
```

I have defined the entity as follows:

```
public class Mitteilung : ISlongooEntity
    {
        public int MitteilungId { get; set; }

...
```

I have also tried to add the following attributes to the ID property:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

In the DB context I have tested the following settings to solve the problem.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Mitteilung>()
                .Property(b => b.MitteilungId)
                .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();

modelBuilder.Entity<Mitteilung>()
                .Property(b => b.MitteilungId)
 .Metadata.SetValueGenerationStrategy(NpgsqlValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityAlwaysColumn);

modelBuilder.Entity<Mitteilung>()
                .Property(b => b.MitteilungId)
.Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore);
```

But no matter in which combination I use the settings, I get the above mentioned error message when trying to save an entity. I also don't quite understand why an attempt is made to update the ID at all when an update is made. What am I doing wrong?

```
public Mitteilung Save(Mitteilung obj)
        {
            var addedObj = Context.Mitteilungen.Add(obj);
            // Context.Entry(obj).Property(x => x.MitteilungId).IsModified = false;
            Context.SaveChanges();
            return addedObj.Entity;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does work correctly.

Note that EF Core will automatically detect that `MitteilungId` is the primary key for `Mitteilung`, and since it's an int, will set it up as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`. In other words, you don't need any of the fluent API calls - or the `[Key]` or `[DatabaseGenerated]` annotations - EF Core will set things up correctly by convention.

If, for some reason, you need to have `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` (instead of `BY DEFAULT`), then the fluent API call below can be used.

If you're still having an issue, can you please change the code sample below to produce the error?

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        ctx.Blogs.Add(new Mitteilung { Name = "foo" });
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Mitteilung> Blogs { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql("...")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Mitteilung>()
            .Property(b => b.MitteilungId)
            .UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();
    }
}

public class Mitteilung
{
    public int MitteilungId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's working! I have implemented your suggestions and noticed that I called the Add instead of the Update method on the DB context ... with update works. I'm an idiot, sorry =)

Answer (score 0):

This will do for all entities

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     ...
     modelBuilder.UseIdentityAlwaysColumns();
     ...
}
```